# Find events which is celebrated on 'Thursday' from data field column on 2014

Tags: mysql

I have tried for 1 day but not getting please help me out 
give proper sql.......................for this query.......................................................

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `events_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `events_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `events_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `events_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`events_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;



INSERT INTO `events` (`events_id`, `events_name`, `events_description`, `events_date`) VALUES
(1, 'club_a', '50 members came', '2014-01-09'),
(2, 'club_b', '10 members came', '2014-01-22'),
(3, 'club_a', '44 members came', '2014-02-27'),
(4, 'club_b', '22 members came', '2014-02-28'),
(5, 'club_a', '20 members came', '2014-03-13'),
(6, 'club_a', '150 members came', '2014-03-31'),
(7, 'club_c', '509 members came', '2014-04-03'),
(8, 'club_d', '75 members came', '2014-04-30'),
(9, 'club_q', '250 members came', '2014-05-21'),
(10, 'club_a', '12 members came', '2014-05-29'),
(11, 'club_az', '54 members came', '2014-06-11'),
(12, 'club_yt', '560 members came', '2014-06-26'),
(13, 'club_ui', '66 members came', '2014-07-08'),
(14, 'club_r', '570 members came', '2014-07-31'),
(15, 'club_x', '101 members came', '2014-08-08'),
(16, 'club_q', '50 members came', '2014-08-28'),
(17, 'club_ac', '750 members came', '2014-09-02'),
(18, 'club_a', '2050 members came', '2014-09-25'),
(19, 'club_a', '850 members came', '2014-10-08'),
(20, 'club_ab', '150 members came', '2014-10-30'),
(21, 'club_am', '50 members came', '2014-11-06'),
(22, 'club_ao', '570 members came', '2014-11-20'),
(23, 'club_ap', '450 members came', '2014-12-04'),
(24, 'club_aa', '650 members came', '2014-12-25');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you need to put some thinking into it and read the docs that were provided. Try this.

```
select * from events 
where year(events_date) = 2014 
and  dayofweek(events_date) = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmic way to do this would be to fetch the date and then determine if it is a Thursday. I.e., assign a day to a date you know and then check whether the fetched date is a Thursday.

Comment: You have already assigned serial number. Fetch an entry by serial number, check it and then update the serial no. and again check the new entry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `date_format` function along with `Year` for the comparison

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
mysql> select date_format('2014-01-09','%W');
+--------------------------------+
| date_format('2014-01-09','%W') |
+--------------------------------+
| Thursday                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select year('2014-01-09');
+--------------------+
| year('2014-01-09') |
+--------------------+
|               2014 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query will be something as

```
select * from events 
where
year(events_date) = 2014 
and  date_format(events_date,'%W') = 'Thursday'
```

Comment: you can use dayofweek(events_date)=5 instead of date_format(events_date,'%W')='Thursday'

Comment: What do you mean by `I want proper answer ?` DId you mention clearly into the question what you tried and what is your expected result ? Learn how to post a question first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there was a slight error in your SQL - you missed the format argument so the SQL didn't work, but just copy pasting SQL and complaining it doesn't work is bad manners IMHO

Comment: sorry for what i have written and u not understood question.....but i got answer its ok.........

Comment: @downvoter looks like you are in the race of community moderator ? Leave a reason for downvote also.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this sql to get the result

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE year(events_date) ='2014'
AND DAYNAME(events_date) ='Thursday'
```